# my stylesheet and images doesn't work with Jinja2 templates with parameters - Django

Tags: django, styles

I successfully converted my website templates to Jinja2, everything works as it should, except in urls with parameters.

I have this is views.py file

```
path("profile/<id>", views.profile),
```

When the template loads in my browser the css and images dont load.

But when I remove the parameter and set id manually in the view function everything works. Am I doing anything wrong?

profile function in views

```
def profile(request, id):


mydb.connect()
sql = "SELECT * FROM account_data WHERE user_id ="+str(id)
mycursor.execute(sql)
myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
if myresult == None:

        mydb.connect()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM account_data WHERE roblox_id="+str(id)
        mycursor.execute(sql)
        myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
        if myresult == None:

            return render(request, 'rostats_app/incorrectdetails.html', {"errormessage":"ERROR 404", "redirection":"signup", "banner":banner})

# gets skill squares
if myresult[5] != "":
                    
    skills_count = 1
    for i in myresult[5]:
        if i == "⏎":
            skills_count += 1

    skills_boxes = 0
    if (skills_count >= 0) and (skills_count <= 4):
        skills_boxes = 4
    elif  (skills_count >= 5) and (skills_count <= 8):
        skills_boxes = 8

    skills = myresult[5]
    skills = skills.split("⏎", 4)
    skills_1 = []
    for x in range(0, len(skills)):
        skills_1.append(skills[x])

    for num, x in enumerate(skills_1):
        skills_1[num] = x.split(":")

else:
    skills_boxes = 0
    skills_1 = []

indicator = myresult[8]


if "user_id" in request.session:
    state = "Sign Out"

    if str(id) == str(request.session["user_id"]):
        config_profile = True
        profile_heading = "Your Profile"
        indicator = ""
    else:
        config_profile = False
        if myresult[1] != "":
            profile_heading = str(myresult[1])+"'s Profile"
        else:
            profile_heading = str(myresult[10])+"'s Profile"
else:
    if myresult[1] != "":
        profile_heading = str(myresult[1])+"'s Profile"
    else:
        profile_heading = str(myresult[10])+"'s Profile"
    config_profile = False
    state = "Sign Up"

status=myresult[6]

return render(request, "rostats_app/profile.html", {"username":myresult[1], "avatarurl":myresult[3], "avatarurl2":myresult[9], "discriminator":myresult[2], "roblox_username":myresult[10], "skills_boxes":skills_boxes, "skills_1":skills_1, "config_profile":config_profile, "state":state, "profile_heading":profile_heading, "indicator":indicator, "status":status, "banner":banner})
```

this loads the css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="static/styles.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by putting a / before the images and the css. I think the problem is that it tried loading it from somewhere else when parameters where in use.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
path("profile/<int:id>", views.profile,name='profile'),
```

Comment: thanks for your advice :), unfortunately that didn't fix my problem.

Comment: can i see your views.py or your html file so that i can edit my answer.

Comment: are you calling this url in an other template in your web site ?

Comment: it works fine without the parameter (<int:id>) but with it the images and styles dont load

Comment: ive found an error, its looking for the style sheet in `/profile/static/styles.css` but it doesnt exist

Comment: can you edit your post with the template ?

Comment: {% load static %} have you use this in the top of your html ?

Comment: first load the static file in the top of your html file  {% load static %}  and modify your link with <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">

Comment: sorry guys ,i don't know jinja2 i didn't notice it.